# Express session inside callback comes back undefined outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, express-session

I have a route written in Express as the following:

```
app.get("/route", function(req, res){
    if (someBoolean){
        someFunction(stuff, function(user){
            ...
            req.session.user = user;
        }); 
    }
    res.render("route");
}
```

When *someBoolean* is true, the session should be set. However, after moving on to a different page, req.session.user comes back as undefined. Checking req.session.user inside *someFunction* comes back defined however. A solution I have found to the session becoming undefined outside the scope of *someFunction* was to move res.render("route") into *someFunction* as such:

```
app.get("/route", function(req, res){
    if (someBoolean){
        someFunction(stuff, function(user){
            ...
            req.session.user = user;
            res.render("route");
        }); 
    }
}
```

This however causes the route to fail when *someBoolean* is false. I'm thinking this is caused by the asynchronous nature of Node.js, but I am not sure. What is causing this to occur exactly, and is this the proper solution?

Comment: Can you post the contents of `someFunction`?  This is actually important in determining whether Node's asynchronous nature is causing this issue.

Comment: I don't have the exact code with me right now, but someFunction involves writing/reading from a database, so that is why I assumed it must be caused by the async nature of Node.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the reason why if it is reading/writing to a database.  You must perform any action you want to happen upon completion of the db call in a callback method to ensure that the events happen in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simplest solution would be:

```
app.get("/route", function(req, res){
    if (someBoolean){
        someFunction(stuff, function(user){
            ...
            req.session.user = user;
            res.render("route");
        }); 
    }else{
        res.render("route");
    }
}
```

using promises you can do it like ( first you promisify `someFunction`):

```
app.get("/route", function(req, res){
    Promise.resolve()
      .then(function(){
          if(someBoolean){
            return someFunction(stuff)
              .then(function(user){
                res.session.user = user;
              });
          }
      }).then(function(){
        res.render("route");
      });
}
```

Comment: Your first example does what I was looking for. It took me a while to find, so I'm typing my question here so others might find it faster than I did: "how to pass data from a function with a callback to the express router".

Answer (score 3):

Session states are saved in one of two conditions -

1. When a response is sent (through res.send, res.redirect, etc.),
2. you manually call `req.session.save()`